# Are CSRF Tokens automatically applied in AspNetCore 3.+ Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've read that CSRF Tokens are automatically validated in Razor Pages but does this also apply to Controllers or do I still have to use the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` TagHelper in my view and the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on my controller method?

If so, I've read on [Andrew Locks Blog](https://andrewlock.net/automatically-validating-anti-forgery-tokens-in-asp-net-core-with-the-autovalidateantiforgerytokenattribute/) that I could add a Filter to do the same but this was before NetCore 3.+.

Is this implementation in my `Startup.cs` correct?

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddMvcOptions(options => {
        options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you do not need to use the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` because when you use the `<form>` tag helper it will insert the anti-forgery token for you (if the `method` attribute is "post" and the `action` is not an external hyperlink).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#aspnet-core-antiforgery-configuration

> In ASP.NET Core 2.0 or later, the FormTagHelper injects antiforgery tokens into HTML form elements.

And:

> The automatic generation of antiforgery tokens for HTML form elements happens when the  tag contains the method="post" attribute and either of the following are true:
>
> - The action attribute is empty (action="").
> - The action attribute isn't supplied ().

Also:

> We recommend use of `AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken` broadly for non-API scenarios. This ensures POST actions are protected by default. The alternative is to ignore antiforgery tokens by default, unless `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` is applied to individual action methods.